# Upgrading to python 3.x

Tags: apt, package-management

Any way i can update to python 3.x? The version I am using is 2.7.11+
When I use`sudo apt-get install python` it says it's already at the latest version.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Python 3 is a different package.

Install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

The run it using:

```
python3
```

Comment: I would just like to add that Python 2 and 3 are different syntax too. If you know Python2 you should be able to learn python3 a lot easier though.

Comment: Also note that `pip` also has a  `pip3` version for Python 3.x

Comment: @Inforcer25 autocorrect?

Comment: @robert I think it's just a typo. `s` and `d` are adjacent.

Comment: I tried this, currently I have python3.5 in my ubuntu 16.04. I did `sudo apt-get install python3` but it is not updated to 3.6. im getting `udo apt-get install python3``0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 184 not upgraded.`